# Como poner Titulos <th> en un tabla usando @model List<Modelo> en una vista

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Programado con **C# asp.net core MVC**

Estuve buscando en internet de como poner los titulos utilizando `@using (Html.BeginForm())` en una vista que recibe una lista y darle el nombre a los títulos con `DataAnnotations` en la clase con `[Display(Name = "")]`

La mayoría de personas en diferentes foros los ponen seteados en el HTML y no encontré como hacerlo, pues intentandolo lo logré de forma sencilla pero si no se dice no lo sabe asi que esta es la repuesta `Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Titulo)` poniendo un [0] adelante del model.

Espero ayudar a alguno que estaba en misma duda, saludos

```
@model List<SIM_Lubricentro1.Models.Reparacion>
```

Vemos que la vista se recibe como lista luego utilizamos

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
```

luego de usar el @using (Html.BeginForm()){

```
<input type="hidden" name="HISTORIAL_ID" value="@ViewBag.Historial_ID" />
<input type="hidden" name="MostrarModal" value="@ViewBag.MostrarModal" />


<h2>Carro a reparar: @ViewBag.Placa</h2>

<br>
<br />

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Personal Responsable: </label>
    <select asp-items="ViewBag.Personal_ID" name="IdPeronalSeleccionado"></select>

</div>
<input type="submit" value="Agregar Listado" class="btn btn-primary float-right btnSRV" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right btnSRV" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalAgregarPiezas">Piezas</button>

<br>
<br />
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Titulo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].DescripcionReparacion)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Comentario)
            </th>
            <th></th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Realizar)
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].ID)
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Titulo)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].Titulo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].DescripcionReparacion)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].DescripcionReparacion)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].Comentario" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model[i].Comentario" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].Realizar" class="form-check-input" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model[i].Realizar" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Ahora como clase use la siguiente

```
public class Reparacion{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descripcion Reparacion")]
    public string DescripcionReparacion { get; set; }

    public string Comentario { get; set; }
    public bool Realizar { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a SO Español. Esto es una pregunta o una respuesta?, o las dos cosas?

Answer (score 0):

En principio, la forma de resolver el problema es en cierta forma correcta.

Aun así, debes tener en cuenta **dos cosas**:

**1)** No estás teniendo en cuenta si el Modelo viene sin datos. En ese caso, te lanzará una **excepción** cuando intentes acceder a la `fila [0]` de array. Para solucionarlo debes comprobar si el Modelo tiene filas **`@if (Model.Count > 0)`**.

**2)** Por otra parte, no hace falta que trates el modelo como un `Array[]`. Puedes utilizar las expresiones **lambda** Y **Linq** que te ofrecen los `HtmlHelpers`. El código sería el siguiente:

```
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Titulo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().DescripcionReparacion)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Comentario)
            </th>
            <th></th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Realizar)
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ID)
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DescripcionReparacion)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.DescripcionReparacion)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="@item.Comentario" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@item.Comentario" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <input asp-for="@item.Realizar" class="form-check-input" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@item.Realizar" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>

            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
</table>
}
else
{
    <label class="alert alert-danger">NO HAY FILAS QUE MOSTRAR</label>
}
```